# remove special characters from json

Tags: json, format

I have a JSON data with format below:

```
//[ { "id": "47356445037421" ,"t" : "DBL" ,"e" : "NSE" ,"l" : "494.00" ,"l_fix" : "494.00" ,"l_cur" : "₹494.00" ,"s": "0" ,"ltt":"3:30PM GMT+5:30" ,"lt" : "May 17, 3:30PM GMT+5:30" ,"lt_dts" : "2017-05-17T15:30:00Z" ,"c" : "+19.50" ,"c_fix" : "19.50" ,"cp" : "4.11" ,"cp_fix" : "4.11" ,"ccol" : "chg" ,"pcls_fix" : "474.5" } ]
```

When I am iterating this JSON, I am getting the following error:

> "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: // [" error

Can anyone suggest me how can I handle or how can I remove // before the JSON.

Comment: Well, `//[` is not valid json format. How much clearer can an error be? I would work fine without the `//`

Comment: And when you fix that error, you can ask on how to remove special characters when you did the research which is required if you read [ask] before submitting a question here. You can even [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/44028494/edit) your question but not recommended when you reach 0 kelvin degrees with that question of yours.